# Numpy array - duplicate removal

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates

I've data set and labels (as 2 distinct csv files). The entries are read into 2 distinct variables (as columns). I want to merge them into a 2D array and remove the duplicates, but preserve the order. Please suggest. Using "set" or "unique" didn't work.

```
data = np.loadtxt('raw_data.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=range(0,112),skiprows=0)
label = np.loadtxt('labels.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=range(0,112),skiprows=0)
features1 = data[:,0] ##channel 0
features1 = features1.reshape(-1,1)
labels1 = label[:,0]
```

Comment: Could you give a [MCVE]?

Comment: I've the data on measured energy level of a set of 'n' channels, measured over 'm' instances of time. I need to check if channel 1 is occupied at time instances 1 to m. But measured energy levels are repetitive. I'm trying to use scikit-learn for this.  The example mentioned above is verification for channel 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the labels can have duplicates? You can use np.unique and return the unique indices, and filter the data values by them.

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'e'])
vals = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

unique, unique_idx = np.unique(labels, return_index=True)
filtered_vals = vals[unique_idx]
combined = np.vstack((unique, filtered_vals))
print combined
```

Output

```
[['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']
 ['1' '2' '3' '5' '8']]
```

Comment: Yes, the labels can have duplicates. Thank you. It helped.

Comment: Happy to help. If the answer solved the problem, please consider marking it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.